# Не работает dropdown меню в Bootstrap v.2.2.1 в мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, кто с таким сталкивался.
Не работает `dropdown` меню в мобильных устройствах.
Вроде проблема где-то тут:

```
var toggle = '[data-toggle=dropdown]'
    , Dropdown = function (element) {
        var $el = $(element).on('click.dropdown.data-api', this.toggle)
        $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function () {
            $el.parent().removeClass('open')
        })
    }

 if (!isActive) {
            $parent.toggleClass('open')
            $this.focus()
        }
```

Проблема в том, что ниспадающие пункты меню скрываются при нажатии на них.

Comment: не забывайте ставить `;` в конце выражения, автоподстановка не всегда может работать корректно

Comment: это код разработчиков bootstrap. это к ним замечание)

Comment: ну если это разработчики `bootstrap` это еще не значит что у них все правильно :-)

Comment: согласна. я всегда ставлю `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашла ответ тут [bootstrap-multilevel-dropdown](https://github.com/djokodonev/bootstrap-multilevel-dropdown/blob/master/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown-multilevel.js). Суть решения в том, что я добавила расширение для Bootstrap 3, для поддержки многоуровневых выпадающих меню для работы в мобильных устройствах.